# *{} class in master page override with another class child page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

In master page I am using following line in css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and I do not want to my grid use this one.

so i put

```
<div class="grdclass">
<table>
---------------------------------
</table>
</div>


.grdclass *
 {
 }
```

but it is not working empty.It override the above one with `*{padding:0}` if `.grdclass *{}` is empty.I do not want use in `padding:0` in my grid table.Is there any way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This code set the property for all the tags in html page.
Since this property is in Master page, You are getting the padding value.
use class name or id name for setting the property in MasterPage.

```
.master
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I want all page uses this one with child pages also but instead of grid table

Comment: master page is my (header and footer page)

Comment: instead of using empty attributes, try using  {padding:none;}

Comment: padding none is not a property.Padding always with numbers

Comment: i.e. {padding: 0;} or your padding value.

Comment: <div class="grdclass'> you missed typing this in your question <div class="grdclass"> or in your code?

Comment: then use {padding:0;} inside .grdclass  @WaqasAli

Comment: default padding value is padding:0px

Comment: check this link for Padding Property. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: default padding value is padding:0px exactly therefore i did not use this padding

Comment: Then it will take the default padding if you don't use padding.

Comment: padding:0 will effect when you use bullets etc...But when you do not use padding it will not effects on bullent and some attributes